# How i fix this undefined method?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

The method 'bulidShortLink()' isn't defined for the type 'DynamicLinkParameter'Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'buildShortLink()'. I'm learning flutter so, can any one help me to how to solve this?.

```
final ShortDynamicLink link = await parameters.buildShortLink();
print(link.warnings);
return link.shortUrl.toString();
```

Here I attached related image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woV2P.png)